# How to change MySQL date format using front end jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

MySQL database has date field which contents date format as `2016-02-28 02:11:24`. Following `php` code and j-query displays date on bootstrap model. I want to change the date format as `28 Feb 2016, 02:11 PM` How to do it using front end J-query or back end MySQL field format?

```
<?php
    foreach ($value as $value2) {
        echo "<div class='well'>";
        echo '<p class="target" userRegdate = "' . $value2->added_date . '"  >' . $value2->content . '</p>';
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

J-query dialog box to display date

```
//Display dialog box when mouse click
$(".target").click(function () {

    var publish_date = $(this).attr("userRegdate");
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'user added date',
        message: publish_date            
    });
});
```

Comment: You could use the `momentjs` library: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//code added the date function with parameter to format date
<?php
    foreach ($value as $value2) {
        echo "<div class='well'>";
        echo '<p class="target" userRegdate = "' . date("j, F, Y, g:i a",strtotime($value2->added_date)) . '"  >' . $value2->content . '</p>';
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This code-only answer doesn't explain what was wrong or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it using PHP then :

```
<?php
 $yrdata= strtotime('2016-02-28 02:11:24');
    echo date('d M,Y H:i A', $yrdata);
 ?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
28 Feb,2016 02:11 AM
```

Using jquery :

You can use [jQuery dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) plugin .

Answer (score 1):

As you're saying you get the data from the database, you could simply format it from there so you don't need to do something on the front-end (or with php) at all. You can use MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2016-02-28 02:11:24', '%e %b %Y, %r')
```

---

in a query like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%e %b %Y, %r') formatedDate, colA, colB 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

With moment.js

```
var date = new Date(*added date*);
var formattedDate = moment(date).format('dd MMM YYYY, h:mm');
```

where added date is 2016-02-28 02:11:24

Answer (score 0):

Other form is this if you want change the sort easy:

```
var newDate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear() + ', '+ date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + 'PM';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bxa5efzj/